# Magento multiple website installation throws error on one website of two

Tags: magento

I'm running one Magento 1.7.0.2 installation for two websites. This is my Apache server config:

```
<VirtualHost 99.99.99.99:80>
    DocumentRoot /magento
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com

    SetEnvIfNoCase Host domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
    SetEnvIfNoCase Host domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tested this configuration, `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` and `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']` contain `domain1` or `domain2` and `website`.

I have configured both websites in the Magento backend. Two websites with codes `domain1` and `domain2`.

When I visit domain1.com, I get the proper Magento webshop. But when I visit domain2, I get a `HTTP 500 internal server error` response.

The logs show absolutely nothing, the Apache log is clean, the PHP log is clean, `var/log/exception.log` is clean, `var/log/system.log` is clean and no reports are generated. Logging is enabled and other errors are reported.

What have I tried to find the issue:

- Set PHP's `display_errors` to true, reduced the error reporting level and set Magento to developer mode: still no errors.
- Created a brand new website, store and view in the Magento backend for domain2: no change.
- Set domain2 as default website (and refreshed caches): no change.
- Created a separate VirtualHost for domain2.com: as expected no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the CMS page configured as the homepage also for the store at `domain2`.

CMS pages can be enabled in the Magento config at [CMS] -> [Pages]